# Javascript Dynamic Regex Generation

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make my alphanumeric regex dynamic in a way that it takes the allowed special characters with it as an argument by the user. Following is my code ... I am getting quotes error here .... any body can tell me how to go about it ?

```
function aplhanumeric(value,allowed){

///^[a-z0-9_\-]+$/i
alert(allowed);
if(allowed != ''){
    var regex = new RegExp('/^[a-z0-9_\' + allowed + ']+$/i');
    return (value.match(regex));
}else{
    return (alphaNumericRegex.test(value));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've actually escaped the quote, so you have to escape the escape

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9_\\" + allowed + "]+$", "i");
```

Comment: @Adi's - I just changed it, try it now.

Comment: I actually want it to accept alphanumeric with allowed characters at any place in the string ?

Comment: Then why are you using `^` and `$` that checks the entire string? Explain exactly what you're trying to do ?

Comment: I want to pass all allowed special characters in a variable namely allowed which would hold values such as "_." then the regex would be built which would allow aplhanumeri with special characters only "_" and "."